# PrintVisual prints empty Page

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am trying to print some .png files directly to the printer.

Therefore I set up this function:

```
    private void Print(string filepath)
    {
        LocalPrintServer printServer = new LocalPrintServer();
        PrintQueue printQueue = printServer.GetPrintQueue("PDFCreator");

        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.UriSource = new Uri(filepath);
        image.EndInit();


        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog
        {
            PrintQueue = printQueue
        };


        DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
        var dc = visual.RenderOpen();
        dc.DrawImage(image, new System.Windows.Rect { Width = image.Width, Height = image.Height });

        printDialog.PrintVisual(visual, filepath);

    }
```

The printing itself works properly but it is just printing an blank piece of paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [dc.Close()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.close?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Media_DrawingContext_Close) to flush the content to the DrawingVisual. Then it will have the content.

Comment: @josef_skywalker, no problem. Devil is in the details :)